# Can we make the "linked" sidebar more inclusive?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, related-questions, linked-questions

The linked sidebar lists Questions linked in the question, answers or comments.

At the moment, it seems to only list them if it's a simple link directly to the question itself, not to a specific answer or even comment.

Can we make it more discerning, e.g. after recognizing a link, check if it's any kind of link to another Q&A?
When that's done, can we have it favor the more specific target as well?

For bonus points, remove a question from related-questions when it's also mentioned in linked-questions, and add a marker there.

Comment: @Jordy: That's only the second part, after properly identifying all pure SO-links to SO Questions and answers. That is deficient at the moment.